# After deploying Django with Nginx, upload images to the admin background and see a PermissionError

Tags: django, nginx

After deploying Django with Nginx, upload images to the admin background and see a PermissionError

I'm a Django project deployed on CentOS,The permissions on the folder have been changed to 777,Permission issues still arise

Here is the.conf configuration file for Nginx

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxxxxx.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/WebSite/static;
    }
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/WebSite/static/essay;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
        location /static/ {
    root /var/www/ngstatic/;
    break;
        }
}
```

This is an error message

```
PermissionError at /admin/home/essay/10/change/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/WebSite/static/essay/20190912140555.jpg'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://119.3.**.***/admin/home/essay/10/change/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/WebSite/static/essay/20190912140555.jpg'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _save, line 266
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

why your upstream tag using port 8081 and in uwsgi_pass use 8080?